# mac custom localhost with port on file host

Tags: macos, host

i have 2 projects running on different ports

```
localhost:7240
localhost:6040
```

I would like to have two custom domains like

```
website.dev -> that points to localhost:7240
admin.dev -> that points to localhost:6040
```

My host file

```
127.0.0.1   website.dev
127.0.0.1   admin.dev
```

and on browser i tryed those

```
http://website.dev/
http://website.dev:7240/
```

but none of them worked :/

but if i write

```
localhost:7240
localhost:6040
```

will work.

I apprecite any help. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "none of them worked"? What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: omg. I make it work.

Answer (score 2):

OMG !!
I make it work. Follow those rules.

1. dont user .dev, use something like .local

```
127.0.0.1   website.local
```

2. On chrome disable the https SSL enforcer
   `chrome://net-internals/#hsts`, add the `website.local` in the Delete domain security policies1
3. Clear cache or history data
4. Vistin `http://website.local:7240/` Dont forget the `/` at the end.